# Checking if a dll is installed

Tags: asp.net, dll

I have a asp.net web app that needs vfpoledb dll installed on the server to work. I wanted to check to see if this dll is installed and if it isn't display a message and link to install it. I have no idea how to go about this. Can someone give me an example of how to do this check in code for an asp.net C# app?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just LoadLibrary it and see if it works? Then CloseHandle it since you don't actually need the module handle